# sql query for finding ID numbers on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the ID numbers for the last 24 hour range. Say I run a task at 4:00AM each morning and want to get the previous 24 hours of data going back to 4:00AM the previous day. I need to get the id codes to search the correct tables. If the data is like this what would be the best way to query the ID numbers?

| ID | Start Time | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2112 | 2021-08-10 23:25:28.750 | NULL |
| 2111 | 2021-08-06 17:42:27.400 | 2021-08-10 23:25:28.750 |
| 2110 | 2021-08-03 20:21:14.093 | 2021-08-06 17:42:27.400 |

So if I had the date range of 8/10 - 8/11 I would need to get two codes. 2111 and 2112. If I need to get 8/11 - 8/12 I would only get 2112 as the endtime is null.

Any thoughts on the best way to query this out?

Comment: You have two time columns.  Please explain how to use them.

Comment: These dates are for system events that get logged when they occur. Once the table hits a certain size it auto creates a new table and adds the ID to the end. I will need at some times to get events from multiple tables depending if the last 24 hours are split across them. Does that make sense?

Comment: So those dates in the table are showing what events are stored by date in what table.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68762578/edit) your question to show us what you've tried and explain why you don't think it achieves the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like that  :

```
DECLARE @employee  TABLE(
            ID  int,
            StartTime datetime,
            EndTime datetime
    )
    
    INSERT INTO @employee SELECT '2112','2021-08-10 23:25:28.750',NULL
    INSERT INTO @employee SELECT '2111','2021-08-06 17:42:27.400','2021-08-10 23:25:28.750'
    INSERT INTO @employee SELECT '2110','2021-08-03 20:21:14.093','2021-08-06 17:42:27.400'



    SELECT ID,* from @employee where 
    EndTime >= GETDATE()-1 OR EndTime is null
```

It will takes -1 day from execution time . So if you execute it right now you will heave only null value in output - because now it's 14.08 and this Edtime is null ( still running i think ).

[DBFiddleDemo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eb1036f6b5393774eea7cb8d9c126b9a)